# Access value in a object using key value

Tags: javascript

i have a object like the following

```
{"7036":{"7073":"","7075":"","7077":"","7079":"2","7352":"3"}
```

How do i read the value of `7352` if that's the only information i have?

For ex: i want to get the value of `3` and in my code i can get the value of `7352`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json = '{"7036":{"7073":"","7075":"","7077":"","7079":"2","7352":"3"}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
for(var k in obj) {
  var innerObj = obj[k];
  for(var item in innerObj) {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(innerObj[item])
  }
}
```